# Выбрать записи из таблицы у которых есть только определённые линки

Tags: mysql, sql

есть 2 таблицы, 1 bonus и 2 bonus_lik.
поля таблицы bonus - id, name. поля таблицы bonus_lik - id, bonus_id, entity_id.

у меня есть значения entity_id например 2,3.

Как мне построить запрос чтобы получить записи из таблицы bonus, но при этом  мне нужно отсечь все записи из таблицы bonus которые имеют другие линки в таблице bonus_link

Answer (score 0):

Для меня немного неявно звучит условие. Идеально было бы увидеть на примере данных из таблиц + что ожидается получить в выгрузке. Если я правильно понял, должно подойти это:

```
select b.id, b.name from bonus b
join bonus_link bl on (b.id = bl.bonus_id and bl.entity_id in (2,3))
where b.id not in (select distinct bonus_id from bonus_link where entity_id not in (2,3))
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но это немного не соответствует моим требованиям. Я написал запрос на основе вашего который выбирает правильные данные, думаю его можно оптимизировать EXPLAIN select b.id, b.name, COUNT(b.id) as result
FROM bonus as b
    join bonus_link bl on (b.id = bl.bonus_id and bl.entity_id in (1,2))
where b.id not in (select distinct bonus_id from bonus_link where entity_id not in (1,2))
GROUP BY b.id
HAVING result = 2